# .Net framework Incompatibility Issues

Tags: c#, .net

I've a C# application that is targeted to .Net framework 3.5 version. The binary worked fine when .Net framework 3.5 is installed.
But it is giving some incompatability isssues with .Net 4.0

I'm seeing the following exception:

**Caught exception at Method: InitializeComponent Line: 0 Column: 0 Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsFormsIntegration, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: Do you have framework 4.0 Client or Full on target machine?

Comment: Is the error consistent on more than one machine?

Comment: do you have the 3.5 framework installed? 4.0 does not contain everything the 3.5 has. btw, win7 already contains the 3.5 framework

Comment: Also, *ideally* your code should be explicitly using the .NET 4.0 version of that dll

Comment: Did you set `Specific Version` property to true for WindowsFormsIntegration reference?

Comment: @Erik I converted that to a comment; you can't *actually* add comments yet (due to rep 1), but we *try* to limit follow-up-questions to comments, rather than answers

Comment: @Marco: I have installed .net framework 4.0 Standalone version from [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17718).  Also "Specific Version" property is set to false only.

Comment: Are you using VS? If so, did you delete the reference to the 3.0 framework DLL and add the 4.0 DLL instead? If not, have you updated your build paths to point to the 4.0 DLL?

Comment: I've been asked to enquire: are you perchance using Windows 7?

Comment: @ssamuel: Iam using VS 2008 . I have been using few 3.0 framework dlls, 3.5 framework dlls.

Answer (score 3):

I think that all the information you need to resolve this has already been posted in the comments, to summarise however:

The information you really need is in the posted exception (emphasis mine):

> Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsFormsIntegration, **Version=3.0.0.0**

Its trying to load the .Net 3.0 version of `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll` but cannot find the file (or one of its dependencies) presumably this is because the .Net 3.0 framework is not installed on the client machine.  Note that the .Net v4.0 framework is independent of previous version of the .Net framework - there is no guarentee that the .Net framework v3.0 will be availabe on a machine even if the .Net framework v4.0 is present.

If you install the .Net framework version 3.0 then your program *should* work again (barring other problems), however really if you are targetting the .Net 4.0 framework you should reference the .Net 4.0 version of `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll`.  Simply remove the existing reference and add another reference to the .Net 4.0 version instead.

**Note:** the "Specific Version" property is a compiler-time setting that lets Visual Studio build even if it doesn't have access to the correct version, at runtime however this setting has no effect - the correct version of the assembly must be present.  See [What you need to know about referenced assemblies in VS2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2005/12/13/503105.aspx)

Comment: +1: .Net 4.0 does NOT contain 3.5.  However, I believe the best path is to install 3.5 on the target instead of mucking about with trying to convert his app to 4.0